# Disabling DeviantArt Eclipse?

Tags: userscripts, greasemonkey, deviantart

There's a script for Violent Monkey/Grease Monkey that disables polymer for YouTube so the site looks like the good older YouTube instead of the new one.

I was hoping that something similar exists for DeviantArt that will disable the new eclipse look of the site and make it look like the good older DeviantArt instead.
What's the script or extension for this?

Comment: Does DeviantArt  provide a link, button, preference setting, etc. that allows one to (temporarily) switch back to the old look?  If so, then a Tampermonkey script should be fairly easy.  If not, then it could be quite cumbersome.

Comment: Would what Brock suggested work for you? A script that auto clicks the "disable Eclipse" button?

Comment: @BrockAdams there used be for existing members at least. new members didn't have the option and neither do people not signed in. some pages still use the old look though. it's not from my cache either, i clear that every night.

Comment: Yikes. Not a big Deviant Art user myself, but that's *way* worse than my last visit.

Comment: @BrockAdams it is pretty bad. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Night, If it was something I could do in a moment , or if I used that site a lot, I would.  But right now, it goes on my list of rainy day puzzles/challenges.  It's currently #199 of 287 in my bookmark folder.  Your best bet is to create a (fake) login and use that to enable the setting.

Comment: @BrockAdams creating a login would make me a new user so the option wouldn't be there to disable. Even if it were, it wouldn't remain after logging out.